# How to install a GTX 1060?

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, software-installation, cuda, nvidia-geforce

Got Ubuntu 16.04, bought a MSI GTX 1060 Gaming X, connected it to PCI, lights on, but actually I dont know how to install and use it.

Last time I installed the Cuda package, I ended up in a login loop and had to reinstall Ubuntu.

The CD that came with the GPU seems to contain only Win-Drivers. Has anyone the same or pretty similar GPU and can tell me how to install or where is a tutorial for this?

Thank you.

Comment: this tutorial seems pretty old... the official nvidia installation guide seems too complicated for me unfortunately

Comment: That tutorial still works fine.  Just open a terminal window and copy and paste each of the lines from the first answer.  You will probably want to change the line about the actual installation of the driver to `sudo apt install nvidia-396`

Comment: You mean instead of    "sudo apt-get install nvidia-370"? So I dont have to take all these hundreds of terminal commands from the nvidia guide?

Comment: I am sorry, I was talking about the steps in the link above of How do I install the Nvidia drivers.

Comment: I dont understand what I have to do, even if I read this blog you forwarded me to... it's still not working. :(

Answer (score 4):

1. Add the Official Graphic Cards PPA

   ```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
    sudo apt-get update
   ```
2. Check which Nvidia Driver Version is the latest: Go to https://www.geforce.com/drivers and pick your GPU, check which one is the non-beta. Today the version is 390.
3. Leave the X server: Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> it should give you a black screen asking you to log in. After logging in, shut down the x-server with

   ```
    sudo service lightdm stop
   ```
4. Install your Nvidia Driver

   ```
    sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-390
   ```
5. Reboot your PC

   ```
    sudo reboot
   ```

Comment: Alt-F1 doesnt get me into the black screen but seach-mode...

Comment: Now I got the black screen but I forgot my PW in the grub menu as well so I cant leave the x server from the "normal" terminal, can I ? :(

Comment: @PortWein Alt+F7 should return you back to the GUI.

Comment: @PortWein Can you update your question with the output of the commands?

Comment: @ Seraf How can I see this outputs? Thanks for caring

Comment: Try to do `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*` before step 4 and then check what's the output after step 4. Let me know what's the output.

Comment: I got an error that said it could not locate package. I changed the command to `sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-470`. Found here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/951046/unable-to-install-nvidia-drivers-unable-to-locate-package/1079837#1079837

Comment: @Tashows can you edit the answer with the updated info?

Comment: @Seraf Sure, I submitted an edit.

Answer (score 0):

After I ran

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-390
```

before

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

in the UNIX-terminal, I ended up in some kind of messy loop. So I purged nvidia-390 with

```
apt-get remove --purge nvidia-390
```

Then I opened tty1 (Ctrl+Alt+F1), ran the 2 commands again and rebooted.

Any more adjustments to make?