# Problems booting - Nvidia Driver + Grub

Tags: 18.04, grub2, nvidia

I'm trying to get my default option in GRUB working again. Currently, it keeps hanging before login, probably on splash screen but I'm not sure since there are just some lines on a black and purple background :/

I can access my system through recovery mode with the resume option. Then everything including graphic driver is working just as it should.

Can someone help me debug this, please? It's my working machine and I would love to have it working again - of course ^^

Thank you!

Comment: Recover mode uses nomodeset. So is correct nVidia driver correctly installed from Ubuntu repository? https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026179/how-to-install-a-gtx-1060 & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers

Comment: I installed the driver from the nvidia site, version 430.40 for a RTX 2070. By now I guess it's not the driver per se, but rather something within grub. I tried nomodest and am trying no splash next.

Comment: Ok, just tried no splash but that's not working eighter ... I was really sure, that it is the nomodest thing because when I resume from recovery mode it just works - with the nvidia drivers enabled and everything ... :/

Comment: If you installed from nVidia with a .run file, that was the wrong way. You have to reinstall on every kernel update. If you install from Ubuntu repository or ppa, then it is updated into kernel when kernel is updated. You must totally remove the .run or any old installs and only have one driver installed or you get conflicts. Uninstall the .run nVidia driver.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/219942/how-to-uninstall-manually-installed-nvidia-drivers Then go back & add ppa and install as in links above.

Comment: Ok, I'll try as soon as I get home, but I still don't think this is the issue - also with the run file you can enable the kernel module so you don't have to install it on every kernel update - at least it worked for me ^^

Also, like I wrote already, everything (including the nvidia driver) is working if I select the resume option on the recovery mode so It probably isn't the driver per se ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with the help of [oldfred](https://askubuntu.com/users/126395/oldfred) I was able to fix this problem. It was indeed the nvidia driver that made problems. So the solution was to use the nvidia drivers from the repository, rather than the `.run` file.

```bsh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-430
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Done!

Comment: Next time check with `apt search`. The same nvidia-driver-430 package is provided by the default Ubuntu 18.04 repositories.

Comment: I will do so! :D