# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Failing to detect GTX 1650

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I've been trying to make my linux detect GTX 1650 so I'd make my dual monitors work but I couldn't. I tried the following:

1. using lightdm instead of gdm3: `dpkg-recongigure lightdm`
2. installing several nvidia drivers (nvidia-drivers-390,nvidia-drivers-418,435,430), I'd restart after each installation to check if it works, but that also didn't work
3. Turning off Secure Boot and playing with all settings in BIOS regarding GPU but to no avail

Here are my system information:
dell optiplex 9010, Ventus GTX 1650 4GB, i7 3770k, 16GB ram

Here some output that may be useful:

`uname -a`

`Linux system 5.0.0-37-generic #40~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 14 12:06:39 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

`dpkg -l | grep nvidia`

```
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-430:amd64                   430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1                   amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-390                       390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                     all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
ii  libnvidia-common-430                       430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                      all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
ii  libnvidia-common-435                       435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                      all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
rc  libnvidia-compute-390:amd64                390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                     amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
rc  libnvidia-compute-390:i386                 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                     i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-430:amd64                430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1                   amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-430:i386                 430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1                   i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
rc  libnvidia-compute-435:amd64                435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                      amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-430:amd64                 430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1                   amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-decode-430:i386                  430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1                   i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode-430:amd64                 430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1                   amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-encode-430:i386                  430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1                   i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-430:amd64                   430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1                   amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-430:i386                    430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1                   i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-430:amd64                     430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1                   amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-gl-430:i386                      430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1                   i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-430:amd64                   430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1                   amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-430:i386                    430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1                   i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-430                   430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1                   amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-dkms-430                            430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1                   amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  nvidia-driver-430                          430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1                   amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-430                   430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1                   amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-430                   430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1                   amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-prime                               0.8.8.2                                      all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                            418.56-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1                   amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-430                           430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1                   amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-430              430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1                   amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

`lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev a4)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Q77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1f82 (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10fa (rev a1)
```

`nvidia-smi`

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

`sudo lshw -c display`

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: If you install different nVidia driver, you must purge older driver first or you have conflicts. New driver does not purge old. If wrong nVidia driver or upgrade, you must purge & install correct driver
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2362351&p=13649946#post13649946 & Install nVidia with newer card, usually better to install newest driver. If older card, you may need an older driver.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026179/how-to-install-a-gtx-1060 & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue by setting the BIOS on UEFI mode with Secure Boot being off. The issue itself stems off Ubuntu not running DKMS modules if the secure boot is on

"Ubuntu is now checking module signing by default, on kernels 4.4.0-18.34, 4.4.0-21.37, 4.2.0-42.49, 3.19.0-65.73 and 3.13.0-92.139 onwards. You can read more details in this bug in Launchpad.

Because of those changes, **DKMS modules will not work on systems with Secure Boot enabled unless correctly configured**. "

As far as I know DKMS modules are part of (or are by themselves) a part of the nvidia-drivers-* packages and as such won't run at all if `secure boot` is on.

Comment: Hi, can we use KMOD instead of DKMS?