# Dual boot Win10 + Ubuntu on separate hard drives, plus multiple screens in Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia

I'm having a few issues here that I'm not sure how to resolve. I'm new to Linux so rather confused.

I've successfully managed to install Ubuntu 20.04 to a separate hard drive in my PC, which already has a Windows 10 install on it. This is main boot. At the minute, I have to F2/DEL and boot from that drive to enter Linux. I'd like to be able to choose (with a default time out for Windows) on switching my PC on. Or an easier way to boot into Linux from Windows. Any help in understanding how to accomplish that would be brilliant.

Additionally, when I do get into Linux, it only detects one screen. I have two monitors plugged into my PC, both identical. One is plugged into the motherboard (the one Linux detects), and one is plugged into the 1050ti. Ubuntu detects and installs up to date nvidia drivers. My display settings has no options for multi monitors, nor anyway to detect and rearrange like Windows would. Any ideas?

Many thanks.

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu in the same boot mode as Windows. New systems since 2012 use UEFI, so both should be UEFI, but how you boot USB flash drive installer UEFI or BIOS is then how it installs.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI  Do not install nVidia driver directly from nVidia. Only install from Ubuntu repository or from ppa. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026179/how-to-install-a-gtx-1060 Install newest available. https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you are asking two questions here If I understand properly. The first on having your computer boot to Windows by default or Ubuntu. The second on how to get your Nvidia card to run two monitors.

1. The first involves using/customizing GRUB so that it points to Windows while giving you a list... Try: https://www.ostechnix.com/configure-grub-2-boot-loader-settings-ubuntu-16-04/ (I cannot vouch for it but it seems clear.)
2. The second is your Nvidia card. If Ubuntu installed properly, which I am guessing it did, Ubuntu should have loaded the 'Nvidia X Server Setting' menu/panel. Usually, the Nvidia software can be found in the control settings panel or just search for 'Nvidia' on your machine. You should get a menu like this...[image]  Worse come to come worse got to Nvida.com and download the latest and greatest version, better yet just go and check their docs...

HTH

Comment: Hi

Thank you, I'll look into the boot option. My Nvidia settings look different to that. It is detecting the card, 

https://imgur.com/PysxEJm

It looks like this. Oddly, it IS detecting the graphics card, but not the screen it's plugged into (both screens are the same model). I've double checked the cables. The screen that's working is the one plugged into the motherboard HDMI port.

Is there anyway to force it?

Comment: I have seen the Nvidia panel you showed. I beleive that it is an older version software. I recetnlly re-laoded Ubuntu 18.40 on my machine AND had to go to the Nvidia.com to get the latest and greatest version. Synaptic did not give me the option for that version, 440.82. Try that first. It is an easy fix. Then we can look at other issues after.