# Dell XPS 15 - Nvidia 3050 Ti drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have Dell model XPS 15 and just installed a fresh Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. I have lots of problems installing it at first but after some time I was successful. I also tried to install the "nvidia-drivers-515" drivers. I had some problems with this as well but finally got it instlled.

**Ubuntu still seems to be using the integrated card instead of the Nvidia.**

This is some output.

```
➜  ~ lspci -nn | grep -E 'VGA|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:46a6] (rev 0c)
```

The system recognize both cards but integrated one is being used.

```
➜  ~ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: 3D controller
       product: GA107M [GeForce RTX 3050 Ti Mobile]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=nvidia latency=0 mode=3456x2160 visual=truecolor xres=3456 yres=2160
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:610-60f irq:189 memory:bb000000-bbffffff memory:6000000000-60ffffffff memory:6100000000-6101ffffff ioport:3000(size=128)
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Alder Lake-P Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 0c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=3456,6480
       resources: iomemory:610-60f iomemory:400-3ff irq:188 memory:6186000000-6186ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
```

From the following output Nvidia seams to be sleeping or im missing something?

```
➜  ~ nvidia-smi         
Mon Oct 10 23:23:33 2022       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 515.65.01    Driver Version: 515.65.01    CUDA Version: 11.7     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   46C    P3    N/A /  N/A |      4MiB /  4096MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      2372      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Why both cards are active?
How can i make sure that I'm using the Nvidia and the drivers are working properly?

Update:
The output from the command from comments

```
➜  ~ glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: Intel
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) Graphics (ADL GT2)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 22.0.5
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 22.0.5
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 22.0.5
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Comment: Hi. the only way to offer any help is to know what the exact problems you were having and what you did to finally get it working. Please edit the question, not as comments and add this info.

Comment: You can switch graphics by `nvidia-prime`. I don't see any problems.

Comment: Please add output of `nvidia-prime query` and `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` to your question. It will show if Nvidia is used.

Comment: I didn't find the command and im not sure how to install it 
```zsh: command not found: nvidia-prime```

Comment: And i add the output of the other command to the question.

Comment: `nvidia-prime` *should be installed but if not you surely can and should install it like any other package: `sudo apt install nvidia-prime` . It is indeed required for switching graphics. I wonder what else is missing... **How exactly have you installed the Nvidia drivers?**

Comment: When you install Ubuntu and have nVidia, you need to choose to boot in Safe Mode & choose to install restricted drivers. Then nVidia druver  is installed automatically. Try `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`  But if you manually installed wrong driver, you must purge first or you get conflicts. ppa not required anymore: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026179/how-to-install-a-gtx-1060 & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers

Comment: I have installed with ```sudo apt install nvidia-driver-515 -y```. How to choose to install restricted drivers? How should i install it via apt or differently?
Regarding nvidia-prime

```➜  ~ sudo apt install nvidia-prime
[sudo] password for ivan: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
nvidia-prime is already the newest version (0.8.17.1).
nvidia-prime set to manually installed.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 6 not to upgrade.
➜~ nvidia-p
nvidia-persistenced  nvidia-powerd```
it is there but its missing

Comment: Also,should i uninstall the current drivers ?

Comment: I have the same problems. Any updates?

Comment: Try install it via "Additional Drivers". For me was formating the laptop. When boot i wait 15 min on DellXPS15 and during the installation i check the button for installing the drivers and everything. Once installed i update and install the new drivers vie "Additional Drivers".