Nouveau Driver freeze my computer with Ubuntu 22.04
This is the log that cause my computer freezing. I have Ubuntu 22.04.04 LTS and I'm using nouveau driver. I'm with Kernel 5.15.0-25 generic because my Nvidia card is a GTX550Ti so the last driver available is the outdated nvidia-driver-390. I was trying to understand and maybe try to fix the issue that cause this kind of freeze/crash. If any of you any idea, any help is really appreciated. I'm using gnome and this is /etc/gnome/custom.conf
[daemon]
AutomaticLoginEnable=true
AutomaticLogin=hyuma

# Uncomment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
#WaylandEnable=false

# Enabling automatic login

# Enabling timed login
#  TimedLoginEnable = true
#  TimedLogin = user1
#  TimedLoginDelay = 10

[security]

[xdmcp]

[chooser]

[debug]
# Uncomment the line below to turn on debugging
# More verbose logs
# Additionally lets the X server dump core if it crashes
#Enable=true

and this is the log of crash:
Apr 28 14:26:26 tr3nton kernel: [ 1973.774783] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Xwayland[2805]: failed to idle channel 6 [Xwayland[2805]]
Apr 28 14:26:41 tr3nton kernel: [ 1988.775354] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Xwayland[2805]: failed to idle channel 6 [Xwayland[2805]]
Apr 28 14:26:41 tr3nton kernel: [ 1988.775930] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp2s0 OUT= MAC=00:1b:fc:4a:cc:b5:10:09:f9:d2:2f:74:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.85 DST=192.168.1.108 LEN=382 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=46410 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=32412 DPT=40911 LEN=362 
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.799730] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.799735] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: timeout
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.799775] WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 4804 at drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau/nvkm/engine/fifo/gpfifogf100.c:90 gf100_fifo_gpfifo_engine_fini+0x168/0x1b0 [nouveau]
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.799896] Modules linked in: xt_multiport xt_recent tls ip6t_REJECT nf_reject_ipv6 xt_hl ip6_tables ip6t_rt ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 xt_LOG nf_log_syslog nft_limit xt_limit xt_addrtype xt_tcpudp xt_conntrack nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 nft_compat nft_counter snd_hda_codec_analog snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio nf_tables libcrc32c nfnetlink binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg coretemp snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec kvm_intel snd_hda_core snd_hwdep rtl8187 snd_pcm nouveau kvm mac80211 snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event mxm_wmi drm_ttm_helper ttm snd_rawmidi drm_kms_helper joydev cec rc_core serio_raw snd_seq input_leds i2c_algo_bit fb_sys_fops snd_seq_device syscopyarea sysfillrect snd_timer sysimgblt cfg80211 libarc4 eeprom_93cx6 video snd wmi soundcore asus_atk0110 mac_hid sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_logitech_hidpp firewire_ohci gpio_ich firewire_core i2c_i801
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.799972]  pata_acpi hid_logitech_dj hid_generic lpc_ich crc_itu_t ahci i2c_smbus libahci sky2 pata_jmicron usbhid hid
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.799984] CPU: 2 PID: 4804 Comm: brave:disk$0 Not tainted 5.15.0-25-generic #25-Ubuntu
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.799987] Hardware name: System manufacturer P5K-E/P5K-E, BIOS 1305    06/19/2009
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.799989] RIP: 0010:gf100_fifo_gpfifo_engine_fini+0x168/0x1b0 [nouveau]
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.800079] Code: 8b 40 10 48 8b 78 10 4c 8b 67 50 4d 85 e4 75 03 4c 8b 27 e8 1a 8a 52 e2 4c 89 e2 48 c7 c7 2c b6 c0 c0 48 89 c6 e8 b0 78 99 e2 <0f> 0b 41 8b 47 38 85 c0 0f 85 6b 6d 08 00 48 8b bb d0 01 00 00 41
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.800082] RSP: 0018:ffffb6abc11878e8 EFLAGS: 00010282
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.800085] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff9b3b38a0d000 RCX: 0000000000000027
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.800087] RDX: ffff9b3ba7d20988 RSI: 0000000000000001 RDI: ffff9b3ba7d20980
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.800088] RBP: ffffb6abc1187948 R08: 0000000000000003 R09: fffffffffffddf90
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.800090] R10: ffffffffffffffff R11: 0000000000000001 R12: ffff9b3a80e15190
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.800092] R13: 0000000000000210 R14: ffff9b3ae1c518a0 R15: ffff9b3a9234bc00
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.800094] FS:  00007f0636eae640(0000) GS:ffff9b3ba7d00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.800096] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.800098] CR2: 000033d8000c4000 CR3: 000000010a594000 CR4: 00000000000406e0
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.800101] Call Trace:
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.800103]  <TASK>
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.800107]  nvkm_fifo_chan_child_fini+0x84/0xf0 [nouveau]
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.800197]  nvkm_oproxy_fini+0x31/0x90 [nouveau]
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.800254]  nvkm_object_fini+0xbf/0x150 [nouveau]
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.800311]  nvkm_object_fini+0x75/0x150 [nouveau]
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.800369]  nvkm_ioctl_del+0x33/0x60 [nouveau]
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.800425]  nvkm_ioctl+0xf6/0x1c0 [nouveau]
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.800481]  nvkm_client_ioctl+0xe/0x10 [nouveau]
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.800570]  nvif_object_dtor+0x7f/0xb0 [nouveau]
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.800625]  nouveau_channel_del+0x82/0x110 [nouveau]
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.800711]  nouveau_abi16_chan_fini.constprop.0+0x114/0x1b0 [nouveau]
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.800797]  nouveau_abi16_fini+0x32/0x70 [nouveau]
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.800884]  nouveau_drm_postclose+0x96/0x130 [nouveau]
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.800972]  drm_file_free.part.0+0x1da/0x230 [drm]
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.801020]  drm_close_helper.isra.0+0x65/0x70 [drm]
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.801045]  drm_release+0x6a/0x110 [drm]
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.801071]  __fput+0x9f/0x260
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.801076]  ____fput+0xe/0x10
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.801078]  task_work_run+0x6d/0xa0
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.801082]  do_exit+0x21b/0x3c0
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.801086]  do_group_exit+0x3b/0xb0
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.801089]  get_signal+0x150/0x900
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.801093]  arch_do_signal_or_restart+0xda/0x100
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.801097]  ? do_futex+0x13d/0x1d0
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.801101]  ? __x64_sys_futex+0x78/0x1e0
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.801108]  exit_to_user_mode_loop+0xc4/0x160
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.801112]  exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0x9c/0xb0
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.801115]  syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x27/0x50
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.801119]  do_syscall_64+0x69/0xc0
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.801123]  ? __rseq_handle_notify_resume+0x2d/0xb0
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.801128]  ? switch_fpu_return+0x56/0xc0
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.801132]  ? exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0x92/0xb0
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.801134]  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x27/0x50
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.801137]  ? do_syscall_64+0x69/0xc0
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.801139]  ? exc_page_fault+0x89/0x160
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.801141]  ? asm_exc_page_fault+0x8/0x30
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.801145]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xae
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.801147] RIP: 0033:0x7f06403f3117
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.801150] Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at RIP 0x7f06403f30ed.
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.801151] RSP: 002b:00007f0636ead150 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 00000000000000ca
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.801154] RAX: fffffffffffffe00 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 00007f06403f3117
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.801156] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000189 RDI: 00000a540003bf24
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.801157] RBP: 00000a540003bef8 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 00000000ffffffff
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.801159] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000000000
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.801161] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 000000000000001d R15: 00000a540003bf24
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.801164]  </TASK>
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.801166] ---[ end trace a277630d3d820941 ]---
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.801170] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: channel 6 [Xwayland[2805]] kick timeout
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.801206] nouveau: Xwayland[2805]:00000000:0000906f: detach gr failed, -110
Apr 28 14:26:43 tr3nton kernel: [ 1990.801230] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 0d []
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.801255] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.801259] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: timeout
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.801293] WARNING: CPU: 3 PID: 4804 at drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau/nvkm/engine/fifo/gpfifogf100.c:90 gf100_fifo_gpfifo_engine_fini+0x168/0x1b0 [nouveau]
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.801404] Modules linked in: xt_multiport xt_recent tls ip6t_REJECT nf_reject_ipv6 xt_hl ip6_tables ip6t_rt ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 xt_LOG nf_log_syslog nft_limit xt_limit xt_addrtype xt_tcpudp xt_conntrack nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 nft_compat nft_counter snd_hda_codec_analog snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio nf_tables libcrc32c nfnetlink binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg coretemp snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec kvm_intel snd_hda_core snd_hwdep rtl8187 snd_pcm nouveau kvm mac80211 snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event mxm_wmi drm_ttm_helper ttm snd_rawmidi drm_kms_helper joydev cec rc_core serio_raw snd_seq input_leds i2c_algo_bit fb_sys_fops snd_seq_device syscopyarea sysfillrect snd_timer sysimgblt cfg80211 libarc4 eeprom_93cx6 video snd wmi soundcore asus_atk0110 mac_hid sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_logitech_hidpp firewire_ohci gpio_ich firewire_core i2c_i801
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.801477]  pata_acpi hid_logitech_dj hid_generic lpc_ich crc_itu_t ahci i2c_smbus libahci sky2 pata_jmicron usbhid hid
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.801489] CPU: 3 PID: 4804 Comm: brave:disk$0 Tainted: G        W         5.15.0-25-generic #25-Ubuntu
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.801492] Hardware name: System manufacturer P5K-E/P5K-E, BIOS 1305    06/19/2009
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.801494] RIP: 0010:gf100_fifo_gpfifo_engine_fini+0x168/0x1b0 [nouveau]
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.801584] Code: 8b 40 10 48 8b 78 10 4c 8b 67 50 4d 85 e4 75 03 4c 8b 27 e8 1a 8a 52 e2 4c 89 e2 48 c7 c7 2c b6 c0 c0 48 89 c6 e8 b0 78 99 e2 <0f> 0b 41 8b 47 38 85 c0 0f 85 6b 6d 08 00 48 8b bb d0 01 00 00 41
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.801586] RSP: 0018:ffffb6abc11878e8 EFLAGS: 00010282
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.801589] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff9b3b38a0d000 RCX: 0000000000000027
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.801591] RDX: ffff9b3ba7da0988 RSI: 0000000000000001 RDI: ffff9b3ba7da0980
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.801593] RBP: ffffb6abc1187948 R08: 0000000000000003 R09: fffffffffffdf398
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.801595] R10: ffffffffffffffff R11: 0000000000000001 R12: ffff9b3a80e15190
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.801596] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffff9b3ae1c518a0 R15: ffff9b3a9234bc00
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.801598] FS:  00007f0636eae640(0000) GS:ffff9b3ba7d80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.801601] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.801602] CR2: 00001dd800196000 CR3: 0000000104650000 CR4: 00000000000406e0
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.801604] Call Trace:
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.801606]  <TASK>
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.801611]  nvkm_fifo_chan_child_fini+0x84/0xf0 [nouveau]
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.801700]  nvkm_oproxy_fini+0x31/0x90 [nouveau]
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.801757]  nvkm_object_fini+0xbf/0x150 [nouveau]
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.801815]  nvkm_object_fini+0x75/0x150 [nouveau]
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.801872]  nvkm_ioctl_del+0x33/0x60 [nouveau]
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.801929]  nvkm_ioctl+0xf6/0x1c0 [nouveau]
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.801985]  nvkm_client_ioctl+0xe/0x10 [nouveau]
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.802074]  nvif_object_dtor+0x7f/0xb0 [nouveau]
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.802129]  nouveau_channel_del+0x82/0x110 [nouveau]
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.802215]  nouveau_abi16_chan_fini.constprop.0+0x114/0x1b0 [nouveau]
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.802301]  nouveau_abi16_fini+0x32/0x70 [nouveau]
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.802388]  nouveau_drm_postclose+0x96/0x130 [nouveau]
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.802476]  drm_file_free.part.0+0x1da/0x230 [drm]
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.802517]  drm_close_helper.isra.0+0x65/0x70 [drm]
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.802542]  drm_release+0x6a/0x110 [drm]
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.802568]  __fput+0x9f/0x260
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.802571]  ____fput+0xe/0x10
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.802573]  task_work_run+0x6d/0xa0
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.802576]  do_exit+0x21b/0x3c0
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.802580]  do_group_exit+0x3b/0xb0
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.802582]  get_signal+0x150/0x900
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.802587]  arch_do_signal_or_restart+0xda/0x100
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.802590]  ? do_futex+0x13d/0x1d0
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.802593]  ? __x64_sys_futex+0x78/0x1e0
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.802595]  exit_to_user_mode_loop+0xc4/0x160
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.802599]  exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0x9c/0xb0
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.802601]  syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x27/0x50
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.802605]  do_syscall_64+0x69/0xc0
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.802608]  ? __rseq_handle_notify_resume+0x2d/0xb0
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.802612]  ? switch_fpu_return+0x56/0xc0
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.802616]  ? exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0x92/0xb0
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.802618]  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x27/0x50
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.802621]  ? do_syscall_64+0x69/0xc0
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.802623]  ? exc_page_fault+0x89/0x160
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.802625]  ? asm_exc_page_fault+0x8/0x30
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.802628]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xae
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.802631] RIP: 0033:0x7f06403f3117
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.802634] Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at RIP 0x7f06403f30ed.
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.802635] RSP: 002b:00007f0636ead150 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 00000000000000ca
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.802638] RAX: fffffffffffffe00 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 00007f06403f3117
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.802639] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000189 RDI: 00000a540003bf24
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.802641] RBP: 00000a540003bef8 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 00000000ffffffff
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.802643] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000000000
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.802645] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 000000000000001d R15: 00000a540003bf24
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.802648]  </TASK>
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.802649] ---[ end trace a277630d3d820942 ]---
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.802652] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: channel 6 [Xwayland[2805]] kick timeout
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.802657] nouveau: Xwayland[2805]:00000000:0000906f: detach sw failed, -110
Apr 28 14:26:45 tr3nton kernel: [ 1992.802708] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 0d []
Apr 28 14:26:47 tr3nton kernel: [ 1994.819607] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: runlist update timeout
Apr 28 14:26:47 tr3nton kernel: [ 1994.819632] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: INTR 00000001: 0000000b
Apr 28 14:26:47 tr3nton brave-browser.desktop[4747]: [4748:4748:0428/142647.554913:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(997)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=512


If Ubuntu does not have the driver, does the ppa work? https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa It was used a lot before Ubuntu offered drivers as part of install. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026179/how-to-install-a-gtx-1060 &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers

Unfortunately, nouveau is not in good shape. I'd recommend that nvidia-driver-390, which should be quite stable. Sure, it is a bit old, but so is GTX550Ti.

Yeah nvidia-driver-390 seems ok, but I just noticed that the issue was caused by Brave Browser +Nouveau driver, I want to test now with Chrome and maybe Mozilla, otherwise I will use the 390
